# A control to optimize data entry

Tags: jquery-plugins, input, html.dropdownlistfor

I was looking for a solution that

- displayed multiple columns of independent data
- did not require a click (or focus) to show the list
- had a simple interface
- supported visible & hidden values (like HTML's `<select>`)
- has color highlighting to show matches
- automatically deletes character entries that are not in any of the choices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't able to find a control that met these requirements, so I created one. Here is an image of the control in use.

[image: example]

The code to create this control is:

```
$('input#scrolltest').menuoptions({                                         
    "Data": { 1:"January",2:"February",3:"March",4:"April",5:"May", 6:"June",7:"July",
              8:"August",9:"September",10:"October",11:"November",12:"December" },
    "onSelect": function(mo, data) {                                        
         console.log(mo, data.newVal, data.type );                          
    },                                                                      
    "InitialValue": { 'val': 'December'},                                   
    "Height": 200,                                                          
    "Sort": []                                                              
});
```

This control is documented [here](http://www.menuoptions.org/)

The above example is part of this [demo page](http://www.menuoptions.org/examples/QuickStartSelect.html)